# Apache redirection of both http to https and non www to www

Tags: apache, https, redirect

I'm having an issue with apache2. I would like to redirect both port 80 to port 443 but also redirect non www to www.

In the following config I have the http to https redirection working fine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is this I can redirect http to https fine, however when I go to `https://example.com` it does not redirect to `https://www.example.com`

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `<VirtualHost *:443>` section, add the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for the assist. Can you provide me with a like to documentation on mod_rewrite so I can better understand the methodology in these rules? Thanks again.

Comment: @AaronCouch As a beginner, I'd suggest you to start with: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/intro Also, if the answer helped, please mark it as such so that the question doesn't get listed under unanswered ques. list! :)

Comment: This does not seem to work for redirecting `http://www...` to `https://www`. (apache 2.4.46).